# How to switch in running mode and debug mode LLDB?

Tags: debugging, windbg, lldb

I am going to debug application by LLDB. I want to know is there a feature can help me switch between running mode and debugging mode? I mean in Windbg that already attached an application process, I can press Ctrl + Break any time to let running application stop and switch to debugging mode. Is there a same feature in LLDB?

By the way, I am using LLDB 3.9.

Comment: tried ctrl+c ? doesnt it stop the inferior

Comment: Thanks @blabb It works!